# How can I merge two seperate two-column sections?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, layout

By highlighting my text, I determined the flow of text in my template document (the red numbers indicate the sequence in which the text flows):

[image]

However, I want the text in the first page to flow normally as one two-column layout like so:

[image]

How do I merge the two two-column subsections? I tried highlighting all the text, and then Page Layout->Columns->Two, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section separators are used to change layout like that. If you turn on paragraph marks, you should see the section break and be able to delete it which should do what you want.

Comment: EDIT: This worked. The section break appears as a long dotted equals sign and can be selected by dragging from its left side to its right side (followed by pressing "Delete").